# C Issue #2 - Double-Linked List for a List of Students

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

So in summary I am trying to build a **program that will allow me to add n-number of students** and while adding them to the doubly-linked list **it sorts them.**

**I keep getting these errors and can't figure out what's going on:**

```
In function 'Ispis':
43  7   [Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type
In function 'Dodaj_Sort':
69  15  [Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type
79  12  [Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type
81  13  [Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

*Hope someone could help me with this! Prepping for a binary tree, circled lists exam. Thank you!*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
typedef struct studenti
{
    char *ime, *prezime, *br_ind;
    int godina;
    float prosek;
}Studenti;
 
typedef struct lisa
{
    Studenti *glava;
    Studenti *rep;
}Lista;
 
void Ispis ( Lista *p );
void Dodaj_Sort ( Lista **p, Studenti *q );
Studenti* Ucitaj_Studenta();
Lista* Form_Sort();
 
int main()
{
    Lista *p;
    p = Form_Sort();
    Ispis(p);
    
    return 0;
}
 
void Ispis ( Lista *p )
{
    Lista *tmp;
    tmp = p;
    
    Studenti *student;
    while(tmp)
    {
        student = tmp->glava;
        printf("IME: %s \t PREZIME: %s \t INDEKS: %s \t GODINA: %d \t PROSEK: %.2f \n",
                    student->ime, student->prezime, student->godina, student->prosek );
        tmp = tmp->rep;
    }
}
 
void Dodaj_Sort ( Lista **p, Studenti *q )
{
    Lista *tmp, *res, *pos;
    
    tmp = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    if ( tmp == NULL )
    {
        printf(" ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    tmp->glava = q;
    tmp->rep = NULL;
    
    res = *p;
    if ( res == NULL )
        res = tmp;
    else
    {
        if (    (res->glava->prosek < q->prosek ) || 
                ((res->glava->prosek == q->prosek) && (res->glava->godina < q->godina)) )
                {
                    tmp->rep = res;
                    res = tmp;          
                }
        else
        {
            pos = res;
            while ( ( pos->rep ) && 
                    ( ( pos->rep->prosek > q->prosek) ||
                    ( ( pos->rep->prosek == q->prosek ) &&
                      ( pos->rep->godina > q->godina ) ) ) )
                      pos = pos->rep;
            tmp->rep = pos->rep;
            pos->rep = tmp;
        }
    }
    
    *p = res;
}
 
Studenti* Ucitaj_Studenta()
{
    Studenti *st;
    char s[100];
    
    getchar();
    st = (Studenti*)malloc(sizeof(Studenti));
    if ( st == NULL )
    {
        printf(" ERROR: Greska u alokaciji memorije! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    printf("INDEKS: "); scanf("%s", s);
    st->br_ind = (char*)malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    strcpy(st->br_ind, s);
    
    printf("IME: "); scanf("%s", s);
    st->ime = (char*)malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    strcpy(st->ime, s);
    
    printf("PREZIME: "); scanf("%s", s);
    st->prezime = (char*)malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    strcpy(st->prezime, s);
    
    printf("GODINA: "); scanf("%d", &st->godina);
    printf("PROSEK: "); scanf("%d", &st->prosek);
    
    return st;
}
 
Lista* Form_Sort()
{
    Lista *p = NULL;
    Studenti *q;
    
    int i, n;
    printf("BROJ STUDENTA: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        q = Ucitaj_Studenta(); printf("....ucitan....\n");
        Dodaj_Sort(&p,q);
    }
    
    return p;
}
```

Comment: `tmp = tmp->rep;` What is the type of `tmp` and what is the type of the `rep` field?

Comment: Your `Lista` data type is wrong, this is not how a doubly linked list is made.

Comment: Yes, that was my biggest confusion, this is a sample from my class. I tried to follow it and try to understand it but didn't get much done. 

Yesterday I figured how to make doubly-linked lists but I thought that this was about that, now I am really confused. :/

Comment: Maybe see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/ for hints about implementing a doubly-linked list. This example contains `int data` which has to be replaced with a `Studenti *` in your case. BTW: You should also get warnings about wrong `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: doubly linked list has two pointers 1 pointing the next node and other pointing the prev node `struct dll { struct dll* prev; void* data; struct dll* next};`